# Formula for subtracting hours from a Date and Time field in a Sharepoint list

Tags: excel, sharepoint, datetime, excel-formula, formula

In a Sharepoint list, i have a date and time field and i want to create a calculated field that subtracts timezone offset from the date and time field (e.g. -6:00). My first attempt at formula was:

```
DATE(YEAR(Column1),MONTH(Column1),DAY(Column1),HOUR(Column1) – (1/24*offset))
```

But of course there is **NO** hour parameter in the DATE function. How would your correctly write this formula

Comment: Have you tried simply  `Column1-(1/24)*Offset` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharePoint, dates are stored as a number, the decimals being fractions of a day.

So this should work just fine:

```
=Column1-(1/24)*Offset
```

Remember to select date and time as your calculated column output type.